# Submit form in ReactJS using BUTTON element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm building the form using ReactJS and if it has `<input type="submit">` element it works fine: forms submits by pressing enter in `input[type="text"]` and by pressing submit element (And there are also working checkings by ReactJS when form is not submitted if nothing has changed).

But if I replace `input[type="submit"]` with `<button>ButtonLabel</button>` I try to use 2 ways:

1. Get form DOMNode element and call .submit() method which is not ok because it doesn't use internal ReactJS logic
2. Pass params to button like
   `<button type="submit" form="form-id">`
   but it still doesn't use ReactJS checkings (I don't want to submit the form if nothing has changed)

So I would really appreciate if someone will suggest me how to submit the form in ReactJS correctly using **BUTTON** element.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The button element should work exactly as you expect providing the type is set to a submit button and the form has an `onsubmit` handler.

```
<form ref="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <button type="submit">Do the thing</button>
</form>
```

Comment: and to add to this, you can do `handleSubmit: function(e){ if (!this.validate()) { e.preventDefault() } }`

Answer (score 5):

In React Hooks (16.8.0 and above), use the `onSubmit` handler and `e.preventDefault()`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Form = () => {
    
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Form submitted, ${name}`);    

    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
            <input onChange = {(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value = {name}></input>
            <button type = 'submit'>Click to submit</button>
        </form>
    );
    
}

export default Form;
```